# Looking for the differences between two lists using loop

Tags: python, loops

I was trying to find the differences between two lists the user prompted.

```
facebookF = [ ]
partyA = [ ]
add_facebookF_option = 'Y'
while add_facebookF_option == 'Y':
    facebookF.append(input('What friends do Alice have in her Facebook? '))
    add_facebookF_option = input('Type Y to add more friend for Alice. Type others if no.')

add_partyA_option = 'Y'
while add_partyA_option =='Y':
    partyA.append(input('Who is attending the party?'))
    add_partyA_option = input('Is there any others attending the party? Type Y if yes, type others if no.')


print(facebookF)
print(partyA)

notInvited=[]
list3 = facebookF + partyA 
for i in range(len(list3)):
    if (list3[i] not in facebookF) or (list3[i] not in partyA):
        notInvited.append(list3[i])   
print(notInvited)
```

If the user entered nothing in the input for the list, it had the following output:

```
What friends do Alice have in her Facebook?         #pressed enter, Alice has no friends.
Type Y to add more friend for Alice. Type others if no.N
Who is attending the party?1
Is there any others attending the party? Type Y if yes, type others if no.Y
Who is attending the party?2
Is there any others attending the party? Type Y if yes, type others if no.Y
Who is attending the party?3
Is there any others attending the party? Type Y if yes, type others if no.N
['']
['1', '2', '3']
['', '1', '2', '3']
```

How do I get rid of the `''`, empty string, in the list? 
Or to be precise, how to make an empty list that prints out nothing?
Sorry haven't format my code yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Avoid entering empty string in list in the first place:

```
facebookF = [ ]
partyA = [ ]
add_facebookF_option = 'Y'
while add_facebookF_option == 'Y':
    a = input('What friends do Alice have in her Facebook? ')
    if a:
        facebookF.append(a)
    add_facebookF_option = input('Type Y to add more friend for Alice. Type others if no.')

add_partyA_option = 'Y'
while add_partyA_option =='Y':
    a = input('Who is attending the party?')
    if a:
        partyA.append(a)
    add_partyA_option = input('Is there any others attending the party? Type Y if yes, type others if no.')


print(facebookF)
print(partyA)

notInvited=[]
list3 = facebookF + partyA 
for i in range(len(list3)):
    if (list3[i] not in facebookF) or (list3[i] not in partyA):
        notInvited.append(list3[i])   
print(notInvited)
```

Comment: Oh that makes sense now.
Thx.

Comment: Did this answers your question? If it does you may accept it. It will be easy for future readers to find the answer.

Comment: Also note that an empty mylist is evaluated as False, so you can test with `if mylist:` before printing.